# How do I loop all table and gather data in SQLite?

Tags: python-3.x, sqlite

I tried by calling all table names and storing them in list[] but how do I recall them?

`for x in list:
c.execute(‘SELECT myoption FROM <I don’t know what to write here probably x[0]>’)` gives me nothing

Comment: It works if I place that in a print command but not in the execute one...

Comment: It tells me { is an unrecognized token. But works if I just print {x}. But that’s not what I’m trying to do

Comment: @mechanical_meat im on 3.82. It tells me syntax error

Comment: @mechanical_meat wait it worked....but how do I take only the name of the table. I see that when I saved the name it actually saved other characters... like (‘ Table name’,) I don’t want those brackets

Comment: That's a tuple of length one. You index it like this `t[0]`.

Comment: @mechanical_meat so should I write ,format(x[0])) ?

Comment: I'm sorry if this sounds harsh, but I think you need to re-read a tutorial. It's really difficult to debug every step of your process like this.

Comment: @mechanical_meat you’re right. Thanks